# Writing a script using tools like vim and execute it in cmd (Windows)

Tags: bash, unix, cmd

I am a newbie and I am currently learning how to write scripts in UNIX. I have used tools like Vim to write a script. Let's say something like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Hi, please type the word: \c "
read  word
echo "The word you entered is: $word"
echo -e "Can you please enter two words? "
read word1 word2
echo "Here is your input: \"$word1\" \"$word2\""
echo -e "How do you feel about bash scripting? "
read
echo "You said $REPLY, I'm glad to hear that! "
echo -e "What are your favorite colours ? "
read -a colours
echo "My favorite colours are also ${colours[0]}, ${colours[1]} and ${colours[2]}:-)"
```

Where it requires user to input variables.

My question is, how do I execute this script? Do I execute this by putting a command in Vim or cmd in Windows, and what is this command? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install a UNIX shell like http://www.cygwin.com/
You can then execute bash script by using the following command

```
script_name.sh
```

Just enter it in the shell while you are in the directory where you saved your script.